# Open a pdf file in new tab using jquery

Tags: jquery, pdf, window.open

I am downloading a pdf file...and i want to open its in new tab..am using this code

```
var filename = result.get('sProviderName')+'-TSCA.pdf';
var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
downloadLink.href = global.rootUrl + 'administrations/TscaDownload/'+iProviderId+'/'+filename;
window.open(downloadLink.href,"TSCA", "", "");
```

but the browser open the url in new tab and downloading...its not showing pdf file.

can anyone help me to do this pls...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try like this:use **_blank** for new tab

```
window.open(downloadLink.href,'_blank');
```

Comment: thank u for your answer..but again bad luck..its opening in new tab and downloading....i want to view the pdf file in new tab

Comment: i think you do not have pdf plugin installed in your browser that is why your file is getting downloaded directly.